# Which of the two audio interfaces (M-Audio M-Track plus and Focusrite Scarlett 2i2) should I go for to record violin?

Tags: recording, audio-interfaces

I am a Indian classical violinist. I want to record my violin along with a software instrument from the iPod at home. So I need a 2x2 usb audio interface. I will be recording the violin by a Cherub WCP-60V pick up. I am confused between the two I mentioned in the question. From the reviews I read, the preamp of m-track is not so good, while that of the scarlett 2i2 is very good. But the m-track has an option for switching the monitor output between mono and stereo, which is of a particular use for me, as I only need the software instrument (Tanpura and tabla) sound from the monitor and not the violin itself (I will be recording in my room, and the monitor is essentially a Sony 2.1 speaker). This option is not provided in the scarlett 2i2. (It is provided in the 2i4, but it is too costly for me)
How significant is the difference between the pre-amp quality of the two? If not much, I will go with m-track, else scarlett.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Honestly, no matter what interface you use it'll have less influence on the sound then your pickup. I haven't any experience with the Cherub... it has pretty good reviews, but I can't seem to quite trust it. — Generally, even a cheap condenser microphone (though not as cheap as that pickup...) will give you better recording results than even a top-notch pickup, so it might be a good idea to invest in a mic.

Answer (score 1):

What software are you planning to record into? You should be able to monitor through the software and disable record-monitoring on the violin track.

I can't speak for the quality of the M-Track's preamps, but you can get the functionality you've described through your computer, so you should go for whichever you think sounds best.

Comment: Oh is that so?! I am currently using audacity but I may use Ableton live once I learn to use it properly. Is this possible in audacity as well?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Audacity, but I'd imagine there'd be a way to do this. If you have both, I'd say you might as well use Live, simply because it's designed for routing audio in all sorts of ways. This article on the Ableton website explains exactly how to do this (scroll down to the "Monitoring" section): 
https://www.ableton.com/en/articles/recording-audio/
  
If you haven't already got Live, it's worth noting whichever interface you go for, you'll get a 'lite' version of either Pro Tools or Live.